# Conflict on submit button when Hit login submit button

Tags: asp.net

I have two submit button in various two purpose. When i hit enter button,but Top submit button only working. how can i rectify this problem. Please guide me. I hope you get my point.
My form is below this Url
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLnxi.jpg

Comment: did you try with button tags? Can you give the sample code?

Comment: did you set the property of buttons to work with enter click event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use asp Panel control to group your login controls and SignUp controls. And set the DefaultButton property to your desired button. Here is sample code, how to use Panel

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="ButtonOk">
    <table >
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonOk" runat="server" Text="OK" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Panel>
```

I hope it will helps.